# IF Statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to insert a row in a table if a variable has a certain value. I have tried the following:

```
select foo from bar into @tempvar;

if @tempvar = '1'
begin
    insert into t1 (f1, f2) values (v1,v2);
end
end if;
```

Alas, this does not work. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: If `foo` is a number, do not compare it to a string (`= 1` not `= '1'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO t1 
  (f1, f2)
SELECT 
  v1, 
  v2 
FROM 
  bar 
WHERE 
  foo = 1
```

`v1` and `v2` can be literal values (numbers, strings, etc), they don't have to be columns from `bar`. You will get as many `INSERT`s as the `SELECT` portion returns.